# comparing 2 times and displaying the quickest - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am making a reaction tester game and I want to be able to always display the quickest time. I am having trouble as the quickest time is always matching the latest time.

Here's the relevant piece of code.

```
 var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;

                var bestTime ="";

                document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";

                if (bestTime =="") {

                    bestTime = timeTaken;

                    document.getElementById("quickestTime").innerHTML = bestTime + "s";

                } 

                if (timeTaken < bestTime) {

                    bestTime = timeTaken;

                    document.getElementById("quickestTime").innerHTML = bestTime + "s";
                }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You comparing strings, which means you comparing how they are lexically sorted (for example, `'b' > 'a'`). To properly compare, you will have to convert your strings to numbers first.

Comment: because `bestTime` is always equal to `""`

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  I see no string comparison.

Comment: @epascarello, I was confused by DOM manipulation is all, but now see how I was wrong. The problem actually is in the fact that `bestTime` is not kept anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time that code runs you are resetting the bestTime and than seeing it to timeTaken.

```
var bestTime ="";  <-- sets best time to empty
if (bestTime =="") {  <--checks to see it if it is ""
    bestTime = timeTaken;  <-- will set it to the current time
```

So you need to define the bestTime outside of whatever function you are calling so you do not overwrite it every time that code runs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var quickestTime = "";

function bestTime (newTime) {

  if (quickestTime === "" || newTime < quickestTime) {
    quickestTime = newTime;
    document.getElementById("bestTime").innerHTML = quickestTime;
  } 

}
```

`newTime` is time taken in the latest play. 
 
`quickestTime` is the quickest time from the previous rounds. 
 
`quickestTime === ""` is for the first play. As there is no previous `quickestTime`, the empty string is replaced by `newTime`.
`newTime < quickestTime` compares `newTime` with the `quickestTime` and if it is **less** than `quickestTime`, `quickestTime` is assigned to the variable `newTime`.

Comment: Please do provide relevant explanation.